# What is the colimit closure of the finite endomorphism spectra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

$\newcommand{\colim}{\operatorname{colim}}\newcommand{\finend}{\operatorname{finend}}$Let $F$ be a finite spectrum. Then $\operatorname{End}(F) = D(F) \wedge F$ is also finite.

**Question:** Which spectra $X$ are in the closure $\colim(\finend)$ of the finite endomorphism spectra under colimits?

Here I am *not* allowing desuspensions. For instance, since the sphere spectrum is a finite endomorphism spectrum, it follows that every connective spectrum is in $\colim(\finend)$. Moreover, $\colim(\finend)$ is closed under smash products and colimits. I don't know whether $S^{-1}$ (and hence also every bounded-below spectrum) is in $\colim(\finend)$. Certainly $\colim(\finend)$ contains some spectra which are not connective (such as $D(F) \wedge F$ itself for almost any finite spectrum $F$).

There's a vague analogy here, where I'm trying to think of objects $D(F) \wedge F$ as being like objects of the form $x^\ast x$ in a $C^\ast$-algebra, so that $\colim(\finend)$ is like the cone of positive elements in a $C^\ast$-algebra.

Comment: If you let $F=Σ ^{-1}\mathbb{S}\vee \mathbb{S}$, doesn't $\operatorname{end}(F)$ contain $Σ^{-1}\mathbb{S}$ as a summand? And isn't the category of spectra generated under colimits by the desuspensions of the sphere spectrum?

Comment: Aha! You’re absolutely right! So we get all bounded below spectra and thence by Whitehead towers we get all spectra

Comment: In fact, if you let $F=X\vee \mathbb{S}$, you get $X$ as a summand of $\operatorname{end}(F)$, so all finite spectra are there, and hence all spectra.